# Combining different dart files when executed by JS

Tags: dart

I'm building up some Dart code that I would like to use in an app where it is essentially a library to the javascript. I'm wondering how I can specify which Dart files I'd like in the project to be part of the library. For example, theres Foo.dart and Bar.dart. How can I have the created product include both Foo.dart and Bar.dart in one file? I'm also concerned about tree shaking since none of the classes are instantiated in Dart.

There's also a Baz.dart, and I would like to have a different build for compiling Foo.dart and Baz.dart into a single file (though this is less important, as I can accomplish this would separate projects and some symlinking).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This use case (build a JavaScript library with Dart) isn't supported yet.
The reworked [js-interop](https://github.com/dart-lang/js-interop) package is supposed to allow to do that but I don't know about it's current state.